# Can I set a list of values to a list of keys in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a set of keys, lets say

```
mykeys = ["I", "II", "III", "IV"]
```

and a set of values, let's say

```
myvalues = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I now want to create a dictionary like this

```
{"I": 1, "II": 2, "III":3, "IV":4}
```

What is the easy (and, if possible, idiomatic) way to do it in python?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary thanks for marking it as duplicate, I could not find it no matter how I looked!

Answer (score 1):

```
d = dict(zip(mykeys, myvalues))
```

`zip` sticks the two lists together, so you get something like `[("I", 1), ("II", 2"), etc]` and `dict` converts that to a dictionary where the first part of each tuple is the key and the second part of the tuple is the value.